# How to make an admin panel or admin application for e-commerce android application

Tags: android, firebase, e-commerce, admin

I am making an e-commerce application and I want to make an admin panel for it. What will be better application or a website. This app is just for my college project and will not be published on play store.

Comment: basically you want to create a CRUD in Android? try to divide your problem in many parts, check this: https://vasundharavision.com/blog/android/firebase-crud-operation-for-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]You could make a separate application which can only be accessed by admins and link this application to the same firebase database. Then implement all the admin functionality there. I have added an image for clarity